# Obter valores de dentro de uma função que está dentro de outra função

Tags: javascript, jquery, websql

Estou desenvolvendo uma pequena aplicação Javascript que faz uso de Web SQL. Desejo criar uma função que retorna o valor de uma variável da tabela VARIÁVEIS, bem como sua observação. Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
valor = pegaVariavel("nome da variavel");
```

Infelizmente não estou conseguindo fazer isso. O código que estou utilizando para isso é:

```
function pegaVariavel(variavel, obs) {
    var valores = { observacao: '', valor: ''};
    html5sql.process([{
        "sql" : "SELECT valor, obs FROM variaveis WHERE variavel=?",
        "data" : [variavel],
        "success": function() {}
    }],
    dbSuccess,
    function(e) { console.log("Erro ao recuperar variavel do banco: "+ e.message) });

    function dbSuccess(t, r) {

        console.log("Valor da Variavel "+variavel+" resgatado do banco com sucesso.");
        valores.observacao = r.rows.item(0)[['obs']];
        valores.valor = r.rows.item(0)[['valor']];
    }

    if (obs == 1) {
        console.log('Observação da variavel '+variavel+': '+r.rows.item(0)[['obs']]);
    }
    if (obs == 2) {
        return valores.observacao;
    }
    if (typeof obs == 'undefined') {
        return valores.valor;
    }
}
```

***Obs:*** *estou usando a biblioteca html5sql para trabalhar com o banco*, [**HTML5SQL.JS**](http://html5sql.com/)

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2):

Não vai dar desse jeito, pois a operação de pegar os dados é assíncrona. Ela só é completada *depois* que a função `pegaVariavel` retorna. O que você pode fazer é passar um callback para a função, e usar o dados apenas dentro do callback:

```
function pegaVariavel(variavel, obs, dbSuccess) {
    var valores = { observacao: '', valor: ''};
    html5sql.process([{
        "sql" : "SELECT valor, obs FROM variaveis WHERE variavel=?",
        "data" : [variavel],
        "success": function() {}
    }],
    dbSuccess,
    function(e) { console.log("Erro ao recuperar variavel do banco: "+ e.message) });
}

pegaVariavel('variavel', '', function(t, r){
    console.log("Valor da Variavel resgatado do banco com sucesso.");
    console.dir(valores);
    // Use os valores aqui dentro
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A variável `valores` tem que ser definida com um *scope* global, ou seja, fora de qualquer função.

Dessa forma em qualquer parte do documento tens acesso à mesma e aos seus valores.

```
// Iniciar a variável globalmente
var valores = { observacao: '', valor: ''};

function pegaVariavel(variavel, obs) {
  // variável "valores" está disponivel dentro deste scope
}

function dbSuccess(t, r) {
  // variável "valores" está disponivel dentro deste scope
}

// variável "valores" está disponivel aqui
```

Como estavas a definir a variável `valores` dentro da função `pegaVariavel()` só dentro da mesma é que tinhas acesso à variável pois o seu *scope* estava limitado à função onde ela foi definida.

Podes ler mais sobre este assunto: [MDN - var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>